# Count the number of the repeated occurrences

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying here to count the number of the repeated occurrences in linked list

such that when my code will display **( 3 a , 2 c, 1 a)** if I'm feeding it 
the list **a->a->a->c->c->a**

```
        class Node
        {
            public:

            char letter;
            Node * next;
            Node();
            Node(char);
        };
```

Using the following function I managed to count the occurrences but not the way I desired.

```
        int Count(Node* h, char searchFor)
        {
            int count=0;
            while(h)
            {
                if(h->letter==searchFor)
                    count++;
                h=h->next;
            }

            return count;
        }
```

In the main function

```
        cout<<"a "<<Count( h, 'a')<<" c "<<Count(h,'c')<<"a "<<Count( h, 'a')<<endl;
```

will output (a 3, c 2, a 3) not ( a 3, c 2, a 1)

How can I pass the head to function such that it will return counts of all the nodes with similar chars ?

Comment: How do you expect the second call to `Count( h, 'a')` to give a different answer to the first call? It starts from the same place, and looks at the same nodes.

Comment: Related: bear in mind that function arguments are not required to be fully evaluated in any particular order.  Since the `operator<<` implementation is effectively a function, the three `Count()` calls can happen *in any order.* That's not your problem currently, but it's possible that your fix might not consider this possibility.

Comment: You need to add logic such that count only returns an an answer greater than zero if you get a least 2 consecutive chars that are the same as searchFor.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not want to count all chars, try this:

```
 int Count(Node* h, char searchFor)
        {
            int count=0;
            while(h)
            {
                if(h->letter==searchFor) {
                    ++count;
                }
                else if(count > 0) {
                    break;
                }
                h=h->next;
            }

            return count;
        }
```